# How am I mis-calling showdown.Converter()?

Tags: javascript, markdown, showdown

In my code, I have a preprocessor intended to nerf HTML so user-entered data won't cause potential mayhem. I presently have:

```
        var converter = new showdown.Converter();
        var preprocess = function(raw)
            {
            var workbench = raw;
            workbench = workbench.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
            workbench = workbench.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
            workbench = workbench.replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
            workbench = workbench.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\\\\\\\');
            workbench = workbench.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
            workbench = workbench.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
            return converter.makeHTML(workbench);
            }
```

This generates an error:

> [FQDN]/:239 Uncaught TypeError: converter.makeHTML is not a function

If I do a `console.log()` on converter, it gives the kind of answer I would expect from prior use. More specifically, it has a few members, including a makeHTML member which Chrome reports to be a function.

The identifier `converter` is only used twice, in the code that I have quoted.

What can/should I do to support Markdown for user-entered text, whether Showdown or otherwise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
converter.makeHTML(workbench);
```

you should be calling

```
converter.makeHtml(workbench);
```